# Simple variable assignment: Tilde does not expand in quotes

Tags: bash, scripting, tilde

I have the following expression that is giving an error, but I am unable to figure out the problem.

```
rcutils_path="~/Admir/bin/gungadin-1.0/rcutils"

# Re-map modifier keys for dvorak keyboard
xmodmap ${rcutils_path}/Xmodmap
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rcutils_path=~/Admir/bin/gungadin-1.0/rcutils
```

---

Tilde does not work inside quotes.

---

If `Admir` is your user name, then avoid the first slash:

```
rcutils_path=~Admir/bin/gungadin-1.0/rcutils
```